# How do I create an instance of Ember.MutableArray?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have checked the docs, but I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to create an instance of `Ember.MutableArray`. I've tried:

`Ember.MutableArray([1,2,3,4,5])`

This doesn't work because `MutableArray` isn't a function.

I've also tried:

`Ember.MutableArray.create([1,2,3,4,5])`

but `MutableArray` doesn't have any method `create`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ember documentation (unfortunately) is wrong. `MutableArray` is a mixin, not a class. So you don't create one directly, you must create an implementing class (like `ArrayProxy` or `ArrayController`). However, if you have prototype extensions enabled, Ember modifies the native Javascript array class to implement `MutableArray`. So if you've got prototype extensions enabled, every Javascript array is already a `MutableArray`.

Comment: How do you do this with prototype extensions disabled?

Comment: @Caltor You use `Ember.A()`: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/2.18/functions/@ember%2Farray/A